# Which one should I install first, windows or Ubuntu when Installing dual boot operating system?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, dualboot

I have tried 2 different ways to install dual boot operating system, and both worked.

Although, I don't know which one should I install first, windows or Ubuntu. what is the consideration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Windows first. Windows will overwrite the whole disk. Also, Windows will want to install its own bootloader, overwriting GRUB.

Then use Windows Disk Management to shrink the Windows NTFS partition.

Now you can install Ubuntu. Select the option to "Install alongside Windows" at the beginning of the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Windows installations think they own the system and don't even consider the possibility that there could be a non-Windows OS installed. So install Windows first, then install Ubuntu.